# Conext for connector actions

Tags: microsoft-teams

I notice that for tabs, there exists the concept of context (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context) which means that the receiving config code has visibility of who is adding the tab and where.

Does such a thing exist for connector actions - that is, the HttpPost actions from buttons created to connectors. Ideally, the code running the Post action would be able to know who was clicking the link.

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost actions do not communicate user identity, by design, for privacy reasons.

If you are building your own connector you could embed the user's identity in the URL though.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Clarification though - even if I'm building my own connector, let's use an example of approving a pull request - if I post to a channel using the provided webhook when the user added the connector and provide an Approve button, there's no way I can tell which user clicked Approve?